# Include script and style on plugin page

Tags: wordpress

```
$mypage = add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position )

add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$mypage", 'myscript' );
add_action( "admin_print_styles-$mypage", ' mystyle' );


function myscript() {
    wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
}

function mystyle(){
  wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media ); 
}
```

This is how I am doing it now, but on reference page for hooks:

admin_print_scripts - http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_print_scripts
admin_print_styles - http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_print_styles

There is notice that this hooks should not be used to enqueue styles or scripts on the admin pages but on reference page for  wp_enqueue_script and wp_enqueue_style they have examples where these hooks are used to enqueue styles or scripts.

So now I am confused, can someone explain to me what is the best to do?

Comment: The calls to wp_enqueue_script() builds a data structure that holds the script files to be loaded and the order of loading. The actual outputting of HTML is done by print_head_scripts() which is executed as an 'admin_print_scripts' action at priority 20. The critical requirement is that the calls to wp_enqueue_script() be done before print_head_scripts() is executed. The action 'admin_enqueue_scripts' is designed to do this. But, the "admin_print_scripts-$hook_suffix" action will also do this but that is just a consequence of when it is done and is not what is intended.

Comment: So I am good with this, I am including it on this way for a long time and didn't have any problems, but I just notice those reference pages and I was confused. Ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need a couple of slight tweaks to your code and you should be all set.

The reference is telling you the right thing, that enqueuing the scripts is the correct way to do it, you just havent called it right.

Try this out:

```
add_action( "admin_enqueue_scripts", 'myscript' );
add_action( "admin_enqueue_scripts", ' mystyle' );

function myscript() {
    if('edit.php' != $hook)
    {
        wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
    }
}

function mystyle(){
    if('edit.php' != $hook)
    {
        wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media ); 
    }
}
```

You can change round the `IF()` so that the script works on different pages. You can also join the two enqueue calls together to shorten the code and make it run better.

Like this:

```
add_action( "admin_enqueue_scripts", 'myscripts_and_styles' );

function myscripts_and_styles() {
    if('edit.php' != $hook)
    {
        wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
        wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media ); 
    }
}
```

Hope this makes sense